# How to raise aws lambda retries upon handled exceptions in the code?

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, exception, aws-lambda

I have a lambda function in C#. This lambda function connects to a SQL server instance to perform some operations. What happens is that sometimes I get an SQL exception in the code. However, this sql exception does not count for lambda retries(in my case set to 2 retries). I mean in this scenario, lambda just captures the exception, terminates, and never tries to execute again.

I want to change the flow such that whenever I get such exceptions, lambda fails and retries according to the "retry attempt numbers" I defined in the configuration.

Can you please help me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

How does your Lambda function get invoked? If it's some events triggering your Lambda, such as the EventBridge event or S3 object event, you can normally define the retry count in that configuration.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-rule-dlq.html

Comment: I do not have any problem setting retry counts. The problem is that if for example I have sql exception in my code, then lambda does not fail(hence retries will not be activated). I need lambda failure at the moment that I have programmatic exceptions.

Comment: can you return a runtime error once you get the SQL exception? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/csharp-exceptions.html

Comment: I have try catch statement in my code and this sql exception is captured by catch block. I can also see the exception details in cloudwatch. However, the lambda does not try to execute again(retry attempt) after receiving such exceptions. I do not have any problem with retries, for example when that lambda times out.

Comment: because you catch the exception, it's handled quietly by your Lambda function. in my previous comment, I suggested after catching the exception, you make a return statement to return an error explicitly. I'm hoping doing that can notify the Lambda function trigger that an execution failed and kick off a retry.

Comment: remove the try/catch.. lambda will log the exception if it bubbles up to the top and will mark the function as failed and subject to being retried

Answer (score 0):

Your lambda function has to throw exception (you can catch the exception, log errors and rethrow exception) for application errors against which you wish lambda to perform a retry. This makes your lambda function aware of an exception in your code and prompt for retry as per your configuration.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/invocation-retries.html